# how to read the value of checkbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li> 
<input type= "checkbox" name="paradigm" id="id_1" value="3"/> 
<label for="name_3">foo</label> 
</li> 

<li> 
<input type= "checkbox" name="paradigm" id="id_2" value="4"/> 
<label for="name_4">bar</label> 
</li>
```

Here is two checkbox. If I checked checkbox `id_1`, using jquery I want to read the label `foo`. If I checked both then it should be `['foo','bar']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the `<label>` elements immediately follow their `<input>` elements, then you can do something like this:

```
var a = [ ];
$('input[name=paradigm]:checked').next('label').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).text());
});
```

A better solution would be to set proper `for` attributes on your label elements (i.e. make sure they match up with the `id` attributes on their checkboxes) and then:

```
var a = [ ];
$('input[name=paradigm]:checked').each(function() {
    a.push($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).next().text();   
}).get();
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsvjP/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
var vSring = "";
$("input:checkbox[name='paradigm']").click(function(){

    if($("input:checkbox[name='paradigm']").filter(":checked").length==2)
    {
        vSring="";
        $("input:checkbox[name='paradigm']").each(function(){
            var vText = $(this).next().text();
            if(vSring=="")
                vSring = vText+",";
            else
                vSring = vSring+vText+",";    
        });
        alert(vSring);
    }
    else
    {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            vSring="";
            vSring=$(this).next().text();
            alert(vSring);
        }
    }
});
```

[**CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/alixo5)

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkedLabels = [];
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
       var label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text();
       checkedLabels.push(label);
   }
});
```